# Exception triggered: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'app'

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

[image]

Getting an error using Python3 and Flask.

In the code shown below you'll notice I've defined the port as 8080. Defining it as port 80 works perfectly well in another app I've got, one that waters my house plants and displays the results on a dynamic web page, but here it crashes with a permission denied error. Why, given both were created in exactly the same way with the same versions on Raspbian?

Still that's not the issue. The real issue is why it can't even be consistent within the same app.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for
from imapclient import IMAPClient 
import email
import time 
import sys
import os
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(1) # number of executor
import logging 

logging.basicConfig(filename='/home/pi/mailbox_event.log',level=logging.WARNING)
HOSTNAME = 'imap.plus.net' 
USERNAME = 'megapower+rob' 
PASSWORD = 'aqp-hRM-2Nb-qh9'

MAILBOX = 'INBOX' 
NEWMAIL_OFFSET = 0 
MAIL_CHECK_FREQ = 10 #number of seconds for mail check

m1 = ""
m2 = ""
m3 = ""
m4 = ""

app = Flask(__name__)

def TimeNowIs():
    TimeNow = time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y at %H:%M:%S')
    return TimeNow

print("Hi" )
print("Mailbox here")
print("Just starting up")
logging.info("Mailbox App starting up")

def template(title = "Mail Display!", text = TimeNowIs(), m1 = " ", m2 = " ", m3 = " ", m4 = " "):
    text, m1, m2, m3, m4 = ""
    templateData = {
        'title' : title,
        'text' : text,
        'm1' : m1,
        'm2' : m2,
        'm3' : m3,
        'm4' : m4
        }
    return templateData

@app.route("/")

def main():
    text = TimeNowIs()
    m1 = "Hi"
    m2 = "Mailbox here"
    m3 = "Just starting up"
    m4 = "Going to check your mail"

    list_object = [text, m1, m2, m3, m4]
    return render_template('main.html', text_to_send = list_object)

def getmail():
    try:
        print("Logging in")
        server = IMAPClient(HOSTNAME, use_uid=True, ssl=False)
        server.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
        server.select_folder('INBOX', readonly=True)
    except:
        connected = False
        server = ""
        logging.warning('Logon failed')
        print("Logon failed")
    else:
        connected = True
        print("Logon succeeded")

        messages = server.search('UNSEEN')
        print("we have %d unread emails." % len(messages))

        for uid, message_data in server.fetch(messages, 'RFC822').items():
            email_message = email.message_from_bytes(message_data[b'RFC822'])
            m1 = (uid, email_message.get('From'), email_message.get('Subject')) 
            print(m1)

        text = TimeNowIs()
        m1 = "Well now"
        m2 = "I've checked your mail"
        m3 = "you should see something here"
        m4 = "that isn't the start up message"

        list_object = [text, m1, m2, m3, m4]

        print("Logging out")
        server.logout()
    return render_template('main.html', text_to_send = list_object)


def printmail():
    try:
        while True:
            os.system("clear")
            timeString = time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y at %H:%M:%S')
            print("Checking mail")
            print(timeString)
            getmail()

            print("Waiting")
            time.sleep(MAIL_CHECK_FREQ)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Shutting down")
        logging.info('System closed by Ctrl-C')
        print("Goodbye")
        #os.system("sudo reboot")

    except Exception as e:
        logging.warning('Exception triggered: ' + str(e))
        print("Exception triggered: " + str(e))
#        os.system("sudo reboot")
    pass
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.submit(printmail)
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```

What I'm striving for here is a scenario whereby printmail() runs as an eternal loop unless killed or a fatal exception occurs which will be logged then the Pi rebooted. You will see from the attached image that main() runs and the list_object gets written to the webpage.

However when getmail() is called m1 gets written to the terminal so I know we're OK up to there but the render_template fails with 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'app'.

I'm wondering how that can be since the return render_template line, and the code that creates the list_object is identical to code that worked in main()

Answer (score 0):

Flask render_template functions expects to have access to the flask application context. 
You can see the render_template implementation here: 
https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/1351d0a56580df36872b466eb245e7634c20dab5/src/flask/templating.py#L125-L141

`from .globals import _app_ctx_stack`

`ctx = _app_ctx_stack.top
    ctx.app.update_template_context(context)
    return _render(
        ctx.app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list),
        context,
        ctx.app,
    )`

You need to find a way to have your executor threads have access to flask localstack context.